# one <A> element in footer not responding to hover or clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, hover

One item will not respond out of three in my secondary navigation menu, held within the footer.  The top and bottom links both work when I hover over them, but the middle does not seem to detect me mousing over the option for some reason.

HTML OF FOOTER & MENU ELEMENT:

```
<footer>
  <ul class="social">
    <li class="social"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Aki-Weininger-104277784411418/" id="profile-link"
        target="https://www.facebook.com/Aki-Weininger-104277784411418/"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"> </i> </a>
    </li>
    <li class="social"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/akiweininger/?hl=en" id="instagram-link"
        target="https://www.instagram.com/akiweininger/?hl=en"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"> </i> </a> </li>
    <li class="social"> <a href="https://www.behance.net/akiweininger" id="Behance-link" target="https://www.behance.net/akiweininger">
        <i class="fab fa-behance"></i> </a> </li>
    <li class="social"> <a href="https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~01d4ae188cd67db90c" id="Upwork-link"
        target="https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~01d4ae188cd67db90c">
        <img class="upwork" src="https://i.imgur.com/Z02P8YO.png" alt="upwork">
      </a> </li>
  </ul> 
  <div class="navi-title">
  Navigation
  </div>
  <ul class="navi">  <li class="navi">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER">
          Home
        </a>
      </li>
     <li class="navi">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER">
          Works
        </a>
      </li>
     <li class="navi">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER">
          Contact
        </a>
      </li>
  </ul> 
</footer>
```

CSS FOR FOOTER & MENU ELEMENT:

```
footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #2a7de1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2% 0% 1% 0%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  position: relative;
}
footer ul.social li.social {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
footer > ul.social li.social a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin: 0% 3% 0% 3%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer > ul.social li.social a .fab {
  color: white;
}
footer > ul.social li.social a:hover .fab {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.upwork {
  width: 2.2%;
}
.upwork:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
footer > ul.navi li.navi {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 75%; 
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.3%;
}
.navi-title {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'karla';
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align:left; 
    margin: 0% 0% 0.5% 75%; 
  font-weight: 700;
}
footer > ul.navi li.navi a {
   text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
    font-family: 'karla';
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
ul.social {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3.8%;
}
footer > ul.navi li.navi a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/daniel-albano/pen/poJydQj?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `ul.social` in the footer. I looked at it in the inspector.

[image]

You can see that it's overlapping the unreachable link, "Works".

[image]

As a test, I applied `display: none` to the `ul` and the "Works" link was once again clickable. My advice would be to restructure the footer using flexbox, taking care not to use any absolute positioning and overlapping.

Comment: But after display: none; the element UL.social will not be visible

Comment: @SharadGaur Right. I was identifying the issue. That is definitely not the recommended fix!

Answer (score 1):

The element selector below is laying over top of the link. If you add a width:600px; to the element selector below, the hover for the link works. Of course it doesn't look great that way, but it's somewhere to start.

```
ul.social {
width: 600px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 3.8%;
}
```